# Async task omits OnResponse function

Tags: android

I wrote login activity in android. I want to this this like async task here is my code

```
   public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
      boolean succes;
    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Retrofit retrofit = LoginService.buildRetrofit();
        LoginApiInterface apiService = retrofit.create(LoginApiInterface.class);
        Call<LoginPojo> login = apiService.login(mEmail, mPassword);
        login.enqueue(new Callback<LoginPojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginPojo> call, Response<LoginPojo> response) {
                int c = response.raw().code();
                if (c == 200) {
                    succes = true;
                    token = response.body().getAuthorization();
                } else {
                    succes = false;
                    mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginPojo> call, Throwable t) {
                succes = false;
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            }
        });


        return succes;
    }
```

Everything looks fine but it only runs code till Call then it's always returning succes variable (I know it is false because of lack of authorizathion)

Comment: "yeaah i know my method return different codes from server but problem is that code runs only till call method then it's jumps to return statement OnResponse function is never performed", how did you actually find this?

Comment: because I'm debugging this code

Comment: Then add a breakpoint inside the callback, not where `login.enqueue` is. In this way, you should be able to debug when the callback is called.

Comment: I have breakpoints inside callback code is running after returning succes variable it's very strange form me

Answer (score 0):

you should not check the response code in if condition `if(c==200)` . the response code is to indicate that the network response is ok. It will always return 200 unless there is network response error/ server failure.

if you want to check the api returns success then you must return success code from server

```
 int c = response.body().getstatus();
                if (c == 1) {
                    succes = true;
                    token = response.body().getAuthorization();
                } else {
                    succes = false;
                        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                }
```

Comment: yeaah i know my method return  different codes from server but problem is that code runs only till call method then it's jumps to return statement OnResponse function is never performed